# Unable to update results of a shared test step via Azure Devops REST-api in Postman

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am trying to update the result of a test case via Azure DevOps REST-Api in Postman.
My test case is very simple and consists only of one shared step that has two simple steps inside.
I want to mark these steps of my shared step as "Passed".

Currently I am doing the following steps:

1. **create a new test Run** via POST request to {{baseUrlTestApi}}/runs?api-version=7.0
   In request's body I pass the test run name, shallow reference to build and owner. Run is successfully created, I can see it on the portal.
2. **create a result of a test case** via POST request to {{baseUrlTestApi}}/Runs/{{runId}}/results?api-version=7.0
   In request body I pass shallow references to the project, test plan, test suite, test point and test case, outcome ("Passed"), state ("Completed"), testCaseTitle and revision. On the portal I can see that the result is created with the correct outcome and state and is linked to the right test suite and test case.
3. **update the result with actionResults** via PATCH request to {{baseUrlTestApi}}/Runs/{{runId}}/results?api-version=7.0
   In request body I pass the test result's ID and iteration details, that contains iteration id and an array of action results, where I specify shared step's ID and revision and outcome for each shared step's step. This is the request's body:

```
[
    {
        "id": 100000,
        "iterationDetails": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "outcome": "Passed",
                "startedDate": "2022-02-16T21:14:14.337Z",
                "completedDate": "2022-02-16T21:14:17.057Z",
                "durationInMs": 27180000.0,
                "actionResults": [
                    {
                        "actionPath": "0000000200000001",
                        "sharedStepModel": {
                            "id": 18338,
                            "revision": 2
                        },
                        "iterationId": 1,
                        "stepIdentifier": "1;1",
                        "outcome": "Passed",
                        "startedDate": "2022-02-16T21:14:14Z",
                        "completedDate": "2022-02-16T21:14:14Z",
                        "url": "{{baseUrlTestApi}}/Runs/{{runId}}/Results/100000/Iterations/1/ActionResults?actionPath=0000000200000001"
                    },
                    {
                        "actionPath": "0000000200000002",
                        "sharedStepModel": {
                            "id": 18338,
                            "revision": 2
                        },
                        "iterationId": 1,
                        "stepIdentifier": "1;2",
                        "outcome": "Passed",
                        "startedDate": "2022-02-16T21:14:14Z",
                        "completedDate": "2022-02-16T21:14:14Z",
                        "url": "{{baseUrlTestApi}}/Runs/{{runId}}/Results/100000/Iterations/1/ActionResults?actionPath=0000000200000002"
                    }
                ],
                "parameters": [],
                "attachments": [],
                "url": "{{baseUrlTestApi}}/Runs/{{runId}}/Results/100000/Iterations/1"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Then I go to the portal to see the results. I am expecting to see all three steps of my shared step marked as Passed in the Details section. However, when I go to Runs --> select my run --> test results --> select my result I see this error:

[workItemRevision error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgZCl.png)

I found that what is causing this error is that in the payload of POST request to https://{{organization}}.visualstudio.com/_apis/Contribution/dataProviders/query sent by the portal **shared step's work item has an empty string in workItemRevisions**.

[empty string in workItemRevisions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OkhUG.png)

However, I have explicitly specified the revision ID in step 3 (in sharedStepModel object in each element of actionResults array). If I send a request to this endpoint myself via Postman with the same payload but with "1" instead of empty string, the request is successful.
Before this request, portal sends another one to the same endpoint for the Test Case's workitem and that request is successful, workItemRevisions field is populated correctly, so it is empty string only for the shared step's workitem.

This is the case only if the shared step is involved. If a test case consists of only regular steps, then I am able to mark them as "Passed" with the same flow I described above.
Any ideas what can be causing this? Is this even the right approach to mark the shared step's outcome? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After checking the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP#request-body):

You could [get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) a request body (use the Iterations detailsToInclude parameter) and modify the request body. and then to update the result to check if it works.

12.14 Update:

If you manually run the test with shared steps, we can get the actionresults like:

```
"actionResults": [
                {
                    "actionPath": "00000002",
                    "iterationId": 1,
                    "sharedStepModel": {
                        "id": 142,
                        "revision": 1
                    },
                    "stepIdentifier": "2",
                    "outcome": "Failed",
                    "startedDate": "2022-12-14T07:43:03Z",
                    "completedDate": "2022-12-14T07:43:03Z"
                },
                {
                    "actionPath": "0000000200000001",
                    "iterationId": 1,
                    "stepIdentifier": "2;1",
                    "outcome": "Failed",
                    "startedDate": "2022-12-14T07:43:03Z",
                    "completedDate": "2022-12-14T07:43:03Z"
                }
            ],
            "parameters": [],
            "attachments": [],
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/Results/100000/Iterations/1"
        }
    ]
```

And then I change the outcome from "Failed" to "Passed" and then Patch the result to:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{org}/{project}/_apis/test/Runs/{runId}/results?api-version=7.0
```

And then I can view the result in the run -> Test results -> The run.

So, I think your problem maybe related to the format of the actionresults, you can try to run a manually test to get the actionresults and then PATCH it to check if it works.

Comment: Which request are you referring to? Post request?

Comment: Refer to the: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/results/update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP, it is Patch request.

Comment: TestActionResultModel is a model for actionResults and as you can see in my post I included actionResults in my patch request... Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, when you get the result, it includes the "TestActionResultModel", but when you use the Patch result, the rest body is TestCaseResult, it does not include the "TestActionResultModel".

Comment: But according to the docs TestActionResultModel is a part of TestCaseResult. And if I understand correctly I can update the outcome of test steps only via updating the TestActionResultModel. I am not getting your point, can you please elaborate.

Comment: I update the answer, please have a look.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your advice. I tried putting the modified results of the GET request into PATCH request's body, but unfortunately it didn't change anything - I'm still seeing the same error... Another thing I noticed is that when I execute the GET request with details about iterations included, iterationDetails is always an empty array, even if I add values to it when I create a test case result with POST request. For some reason iterationDetails get populated only after I send the PATCH request, not sure if this is the expected behavior.

Comment: @AlexanderWakka I have edited the answer, please have a look.